# Why blank card with no content populates in Bot Emulator as a response to query?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to test a bot on emulator. It is responding good with a card with content in it for the coded part. But when the keywords other than coding part is given as a input, which is expected to be connected with Knowledge base, the blank card is populated in the chat. Not able to understand whether it is connected to the knowledge base or not. And if it is connected, why respected answer is not populated in the card.

[Please go through the screenshot attached of the responses in the window by clicking on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyvxn.png)

Comment: Can you try [Test your knowledge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/test-knowledge-base) and also see [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/2337)

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT   Thank you for your response.

I have tested Knowledge Base, it is working good and also checked on other bot.
And about the second issue you stated above about the version, if you see the screenshot the first response is itself a adaptive card and content is written in it. So, I think if there would be a issue of version, that card should also have not to be  populated. 
Please give your view on it and kindly know me what I have to share for your understanding.